# Override parameter with a space in the parameter name

Tags: azure-pipelines

In an [Azure Resource Group Deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops), can I **override** a **parameter** that has a space in its **name**?

I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy) to create an Azure resource group deployment project.  In that project I'm able to create parameters with spaces in the name and successfully deploy it via Visual Studio.

*azuredeploy.json*

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "My easy to read parameter": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "hello world"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('My easy to read parameter')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('StorageType')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "MyTag"
      },
      "kind": "Storage"
    }
  ]
}
```

It appears I can override parameters using this: 
`overrideParameters: '-myNotSoEasyToReadParameter integration-webfarm'` [source](https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2019/09/02/everything-as-code-with-azure-devops-pipelines-c-arm-and-yaml-part-4-deploying-an-arm-template-to-create-an-azure-app-service-with-code/).

How do I do that on a parameter w/ spaces?

`overrideParameters: '-My easy to read parameter integration-webfarm'`

Comment: Can you share the log of the Azure Resource Group Deployment task?So I can judge which parameters are used in the API according your service .The parameters set in override template parameters need to be used in the API. If they are not used, it is meaningless to override them.

Comment: Hi @HughLin-MSFT - thanks for the reply.  I haven't tried running it as I know I don't have the correct syntax.  I am confident I'm using the parameter.  I've updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **Yes** and **No**.

The **Yes** means this special parameter name `My easy to read parameter` can be override. And **No** means the approach you are using is not correct.

Firstly, `hello world` is a invalid value. Since what you defined it is a `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts` type, it does not allow you to use the characters other than lowercase letters and numbers, including spaces.

To achieve overriding the parameter name `My easy to read parameter`, you can not directly override it in the task configuration:

[image]

The name with spaces could not be recognized by the task. Because of the spaces, this task could not treat this special name as one completed string and will try to parse it. Then you would received the error like follow show:

[image]

Even not work by using double quotes around it.

---

The correct and succeed overriding method is using Override Parameter json file.

Create a new parameter json file, then specified the parameter name and value which you want to be override.

For example:

**(1).** This is my **template json file** which parameter name is `My easy to read parameter` and value is `merlinliang`:

[image]

**(2).** Now, create a another **parameter json file**. Specified a new value `merlinoverride` in it:

[image]

**(3).** In ARM deploy task configuration, configure like this:

[image]

You can see the name was override successfully:

[image]

Comment: I guess I couldn’t pass parameters from my pipeline down then  if the only option is a params file

Comment: @spottedmahn. Any limitation? Because only there 2 method can override the parameter in this task. One is directly specify in the input box under **Override template parameters** by using `-{name} {new value}`. And another one is using parameter file.